# JavaScript regex refactoring

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm performing this on a string:

```
var poo = poo
.replace(/[%][<]/g, "'<")
.replace(/[>][%]/g, ">'")
.replace(/[%]\s*[+]/g, "'+")
.replace(/[+]\s*[%]/g, "+'");
```

Given the similar if these statements, can these regexs be comebined somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think so. At least, I suspect for any transformation involving fewer replaces I can come up with a string that your original and the proposed alternative treat differently. However, it may be that the text you're working with wouldn't trigger the differences, and so for practical purposes a shorter transformation would work as well. Depends on the text.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very delightful response. I'll have to register so I can upvote!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it a little bit.  You don't need all the range syntax

```
poo
.replace(/%</g, "'<")
.replace(/>%/g, ">'")
.replace(/%\s*\+/g, "'+")
.replace(/\+\s*%/g, "+'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in either case, the replacement only turns `%` into `'` and removes spaces:

```
var poo = 'some annoying %< string >% with some %  + text  +   %';

poo = poo.replace(/%<|>%|%\s*\+|\+\s*%/g, function(match) { 
  return match.replace('%', '\'').replace(/\s/g,''); 
});

// "some annoying '< string >' with some ' + text + '"
```

Although that's not much simpler...

Answer (score 0):

Using lookahead assertions and capturing:

```
var poo = poo.replace(/%(?=<)|(>)%|%\s*(?=\+)|(\+)\s*%/g, "$1$2'");
```

Using capturing alone:

```
var poo = poo.replace(/(>)%|(\+)\s*%|%(<)|%\s*(\+)/g, "$1$2'$3$4");
```

If JS's RegExp supported lookbehind assertions:

```
var poo = poo.replace(/%(?=<)|(?<=>)%|%\s*(?=\+)|(?<=\+)\s*%/g, "'");
```

but it doesn't.